# Correct dtype definition

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have a couple of huge (1.7GB) csv files, where I have to reorganise the data structure.
So in the first place I read in the file to determine the dimensions of the numpy array I have to create and then I could start filling the array. My problem is, that the first column in the array has to be of type String ('|S12') and the rest have to be floats ('

I thought to define the numpy.dtype in this way: `dt = np.dtype('|S12',('<f8', 51))`.
The number for the floats would be a variable in the end.
When I create the array, using `dt` then I get an array of strings.

```
z = np.zeros( (2,52), dtype=dt)
```

How would the correct type definition look like?

Cheers, Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this instead:

```
def make_dtype(n_float_cols):
    spec = dict(
        names=['name'] + ['f{:03d}'.format(i) for i in range(n_float_cols)],
        formats=['|S12'] + ['<f8'] * n_float_cols,
    )
    return np.dtype(spec)

dt = make_dtype(51)
```

Adjust to taste.

Comment: This is a nice way to create the dtype, but note that if you use `z = np.zeros( (2,52), dtype=dt)`, you will not get the array you expect.

Answer (score 1):

The solution closest to your original attempt is this:

```
n = 6 # easier to test than 51 :P
dt = np.dtype([('name', 'S12'), ('values', '<f8', n)])
```

where you can replace `'name'` and `'values'` with any names of your choosing.  Then, to make an empty array, don't specify the number of columns, since technically an array with a structured dtype is only 1d:

```
>>> np.zeros(2, dtype=dt)
array([('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('', [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])], 
      dtype=[('name', 'S12'), ('values', '<f8', (6,))])
```

To access the array, you can get the strings with `z['name']`, and all the floats with `z['values']`:

```
>>> z['name']
array(['', ''], 
      dtype='|S12')

>>> z['values']
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

If you choose to use @Robert's solution, you'll still have to specify only the number of rows when you create your array.  Note the difference though, is that the floats are individual fields, as opposed to one field with all the floats as above:

```
>>> np.zeros(2, dtype=make_dtype(6))
array([('', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
       ('', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)], 
      dtype=[('name', 'S12'), ('f000', '<f8'), ('f001', '<f8'), ('f002', '<f8'), ('f003', '<f8'), ('f004', '<f8'), ('f005', '<f8')])
```

Here you access the strings the same way, but you can only access one field (like a column) of the floats at a time:

```
>>> z['name']
array(['', ''], 
      dtype='|S12')

>>> z['f000']
array([ 0.,  0.])
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer. I think I prefer Roberts approach for the fact that the floats are individual fields. What escapes me still is how to access an individual float field. `z['f003',1]´ doesn't give me the value back. Bests Thomas

Comment: Keep the field access separate from the row access. `z['f003'][1]` or `z[1]['f003']` to taste.